# Xamarin Forms upload image Laravel POST Request failed

Tags: android, xamarin, http-post, xamarin-forms-4

If I upload over Insomnia an image to my Laravel application everything is ok and I get following log

```
[2020-03-04 05:26:39] local.DEBUG: array (
  'image' => 
  Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(
     'test' => false,
     'originalName' => 'Screenshot_1583210368.png',
     'mimeType' => 'image/png',
     'error' => 0,
     'hashName' => NULL,
  )),
)
```

But if I upload an image on android emulator the log file in Laravel looks like (1000+ lines) :

`` �"@�G����ޠ��U��H��I�G"Ĉ`.SB^G ``

This is my Xamarin Function :

```
public async Task<string> uploadImage(Stream stream)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {


                var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();


                content.Add(new StreamContent(stream),"image");


                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", (Application.Current.Properties["access_token"].ToString()));


                var result = await client.PostAsync("https://example.com/api/upload/image", content);

                return "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make sure the stream you use is right and here is [an example](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/267762/#Comment_267762) of upload image to sever side, pay attention to the line `content.Add...`.

Comment: Thanks it works :)

Comment: Can you please mark the answer so that we can help more people with same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Example of uploading a image to server side in Xamarin:

```
private MediaFile _image;

// code here to assign image to _image

var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StreamContent(_image.GetStream()), "\"file\"", $"\"{_image.Path}\"");

var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
var url = "http://upload.here.io/folder/subdir";
var responseMsg = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);

var remotePath =  await responseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```